# Apparent discrepancy between a parametric function / curve and its corresponding $y=f(x)$ expression.

Tags: calculus, soft-question, definition, parametric

If I am correct , a parametric function/ curve in $2D$  is a function that takes all the elements of a set $T$  ( $\subset R$) as inputs and that sends back each time as output an element of $R^2$, that is a couple or a point $P=(X_P, Y_P)$ with $X_P= f(t)$ and $Y_P= g(t)$.

For example, if one sets $f(t)=t^2$ and $g(t)=t^3+1$, the corresponding parametric function defined , say, on $T= [0,10]$ should be ( at least if I am right as to the definition of a parametric function):

$\{(X_P,Y_P) |\space 0\leq t\leq 10 \space\&\space  X_P=t^2 \space\& \space Y_P=t^3+1\}$.

When I ask Desmos to draw the graph of the parametric function $(f(t), g(t)$) I get a line that looks ( somehow ) like the $\sqrt(x)$ function.

But, when I try to recover the y=f(x) expression of the function , I find ( with $t\geq 0$)

$y=x^\frac{3}{2}+1 $, the graph of which looks roughly like the $x^2$ function.

So, is my definiton of a parametric function not correct? What do I miss?

[image]

Here a screenshot of Herbert Gross' calculus lectures which occasionned my research :

[image]

Comment: You asked Desmos to plot $f(t) = t^3 + 1$ and $g(t) = t^2$, which is the opposite of what's in your post. (As expected, the two graphs are reflection-symmetric about the line $y = x$. :)

Comment: I was already thoughtmless when  was a schoolboy.. Thanks

Comment: It happens to us all. :)